# In Swift, check if a key exists in JSON

Tags: json, swift2

I have the following function. It is supposed to take the current song playing information from the API webpage. When a song is playing, the page says:

> { "artist" : "Artist", "song" : "Song" }

When no data is available (No song is playing):

> { "error" : "no song metadata provided" }

Is there a way to check if the "error" key exists? Or what can I do with this issue?

```
func songNowPlaying() {
    let endpoint = NSURL(string: "http://api.vicradio.org/songs/current")
    let jsonData = NSData(contentsOfURL: endpoint!)

    do {
        let parsed = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as! NSMutableArray
        SongNowText.text = parsed.valueForKey("song").componentsJoinedByString("")
        ArtistNowText.text = parsed.valueForKey("artist").componentsJoinedByString("")
    }
    catch let error as NSError {
        print("\(error)")
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not savvy with my Swift, but wouldn't `parsed.valueForKey("song")` raise an error and then in your `catch` block you could access the `error` key?

Comment: @Sam That's a smart idea. The error I was getting is different than what I expected. When there is the "error" case, it will only let me parse as an NSMutableArray? I don't understand, but I'll keep playing around with it. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The URL returns a JSON dictionary not an array. You can check for both cases this way

```
func songNowPlaying() {
  let endpoint = NSURL(string: "http://api.vicradio.org/songs/current")
  if let jsonData = NSData(contentsOfURL: endpoint!) {

    do {
      let parsed = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData, options: .MutableContainers) as! [String:String]
      if let error = parsed["error"] {
        print("Result error: \(error)")
      } else {
        if let song = parsed["song"] { 
          SongNowText.text = song 
        }
        if let artist = parsed["artist"] { 
          ArtistNowText.text = artist
        }
      }
    }
    catch let error as NSError {
      print("Serialization error: \(error)")
    }
  }
}
```

as the JSON object can be downcasted to `[String:String]` any further downcasting is not needed.

Comment: Oh no, when the information changed from "song" and "artist" to "error" I got "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

Comment: you didn't mention that the other keys could be optional, too. I updated the post

Comment: My mistake, I apologize. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry again, but I got the "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" again. It says EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION on the line "let parsed = try ...". Any ideas on this?

Comment: Then the data downloaded from the URL could be invalid. i'll update the post to consider this case, too

Comment: I'm just learning about JSON parsing in Swift, so I appreciate the help.